# MySQL Wordpress data search query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to pull some data from a MySQL database as part of a Wordpress website to move it to a new Wordpress website.

I am trying to grab all posts in a certain category so that I can export them.  In plain English, I'm trying to do the following:

1. In table **wp_term_relationships** table get a list of all the **object_id** numbers that are associated with **term_taxonomy_id** "17"
2. Then - in **wp_posts** search for all rows with **ID** = to the **object_id** list from point 1

I don't mind manually building a search term with the entries resulting from point 1 as there are only 88 if its easier just to skip to point 2?

I'm using Sequel Pro & mysqlworkbench query tools to access the database & export/import & manipulate the data.

Thanks

**UPDATE** Here is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `ID` = '535' ORDER BY `post_author` LIMIT 0,1000
```

I want to effectively search for ID 535 , 536, 153, etc...

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE 
(
    (`ID` = '535') OR (`ID` = '539') OR (`ID` = '803') OR  (`ID` = '919') OR  (`ID` = '958') OR (`ID` = '1188') OR (`ID` = '1284') OR (`ID` = '1287') OR (`ID` = '1332') OR (`ID` = '1359') OR (`ID` = '1378') OR (`ID` = '1450') OR (`ID` = '1474') OR (`ID` = '1543') OR (`ID` = '1547') OR (`ID` = '1556') OR (`ID` = '1573') OR (`ID` = '1596') OR (`ID` = '1598') OR (`ID` = '1677') OR (`ID` = '1706') OR (`ID` = '1708') OR (`ID` = '1813') OR (`ID` = '1868') OR (`ID` = '1956') OR (`ID` = '1979') OR (`ID` = '2013') OR (`ID` = '2020') OR (`ID` = '2089') OR (`ID` = '2159') OR (`ID` = '2201') OR (`ID` = '2231') OR (`ID` = '2243') OR (`ID` = '2409') OR (`ID` = '2506') OR (`ID` = '2572') OR (`ID` = '2721') OR (`ID` = '3337') OR (`ID` = '3421') OR (`ID` = '3481') OR (`ID` = '3625') OR (`ID` = '3701') OR (`ID` = '3706') OR (`ID` = '4013') OR (`ID` = '4182') OR (`ID` = '4276') OR (`ID` = '4328') OR (`ID` = '4373') OR (`ID` = '4405') OR (`ID` = '4438') OR (`ID` = '4506') OR (`ID` = '4565') OR (`ID` = '4628') OR (`ID` = '4681') OR (`ID` = '4732') OR (`ID` = '4767') OR (`ID` = '4836') OR (`ID` = '4920') OR (`ID` = '4968') OR (`ID` = '5017') OR (`ID` = '5038') OR (`ID` = '5115') OR (`ID` = '5144') OR (`ID` = '5215') OR (`ID` = '5244') OR (`ID` = '5318') OR (`ID` = '5339') OR (`ID` = '5384') OR (`ID` = '5406') OR (`ID` = '5450') OR (`ID` = '5515') OR (`ID` = '5821') OR (`ID` = '6070') OR (`ID` = '6178') OR (`ID` = '6238') OR (`ID` = '6288') OR (`ID` = '6355') OR (`ID` = '6510') OR (`ID` = '6612') OR (`ID` = '6690') OR (`ID` = '6756') OR (`ID` = '6776') OR (`ID` = '6792') OR (`ID` = '6822') OR (`ID` = '6835') OR (`ID` = '7631') OR (`ID` = '8241') OR (`ID` = '8671')
)
ORDER BY `post_author`
```

Comment: You should read about [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html).